# Get currently logged in user from controller in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to take out currently logged in user from Controller.java in swing application based on MVC. Users are stored in txt file(int id, String name, String address, boolean isAdmin)

There is a method created in controller

```
public void addListeners(){

    loginListener=new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String username=view.getLogin().getLoginUsername().getText();
            char[] password = view.getLogin().getLoginPassword().getPassword();


            String pass="";
            for(int i=0;i<password.length;i++){
                pass+=password[i];
            }

            System.out.println("Username "+username+",password "+pass);
            boolean correctUser=false;
            boolean admin=false;
            for(User user : model.getShop().getUsers()){
                if(username.equals(user.getUsername()) && pass.equals(user.getPassword())){
                    correctUser=true;
                    admin=user.isAdmin();
                    break;
                }   
            }
            if(correctUser){
                view.changeToMaineMenu();
                view.getMainmenu().addTabs(admin);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Not a valid user");


            view.getLogin().getLoginUsername().setText("");
            view.getLogin().getLoginPassword().setText("");
            viewSuppliers();
        }

    };
```

I want to create special user actions depends on who is logged: user or admin ie. create new customer for admin only.

I don't know how to access to that. Any help highly appreciated.

What are recommended methods to store logged users in mvc in swing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to create special user actions depends on who is logged: user or admin ie. create new customer for admin only.*

I think [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) as exemplified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913087/1795530) might help you to keep the logged in user "global". Then you can ask for user's role (admin or simple user) in order to add the special actions you need.

I'd start wrapping all user data in a domain class (a simple [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)) and then implement a `SessionManager`.