# How to separate User data from my Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

I am working on a Swing GUI, which consists of several panels, tables and table models which are connected to an underlying MySQL database using Hibernate.

My current aim is to store information about the *current user*, id and table name, in a kind of History/Log table.

The problem I'm facing is that I have to pass the user name to all panels to the table model, because this last one is the responsible to create a new log record in case of UPDATE, SAVE, DELETE events.

I am thinking about a way to separate ***user*** variable from panels/table models.
This at least would spare the pass-through of user variable through panels.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You need to show the code related to your question.

Comment: Not all questions need code, especially if these are about design concerns like this case. What code would you like to see? All OP's table models? All the panels? I don't think so. @Stefan

Comment: You could look at Mediator Pattern : http://blue-walrus.com/2013/06/mediator-pattern-in-swing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the answer to this question: [Get currently logged in user from controller in java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25533905/1795530), using [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is an elegant solution to keep current user's data "global" and accessible in the entire life-cycle of your application, from user's log-in until user's log-out.

See an example of implementation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913087/1795530).

Comment: Thanks, this is a very elegant solution, like it.